# Setting max size of contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I wonder if I could set the max size of contenteditable element, preventing it from typing more characters than the editable "window" width is.

I have something like this:
`<h2 contenteditable="true">My text</h2>`

The `h2` element has it's own size and style:

```
h2 {
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
width: 300px;
max-width: 300px;
height: 15px;
max-height: 15px;
}
```

Now, when I reach the max size, I can type more characters and it looks like I jump into next line. When I hit ***enter*** button i also jump down into next line/raw.

What I want to reach is to block this editable content "window" when I reach their max width and block the possibility to increase the height by hitting ***enter*** button.

I want to know if it is possible to do it using html5/css or only chance is to create some javascript code?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You use following statement

```
<h2 contenteditable="true">My text</h2>
```

But you didn't apply settings for h2.So,replace h4 to h2.

```
h2 {
display: inline-block;
overflow: hidden;
width: 300px;
max-width: 300px;
height: 15px;
max-height: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it is h2 in all places. My mistake i correct it. Its not a solution.

Comment: set width: auto; property in to h2 style.

Comment: but look, when you reach the max width your cursor is going to start position and you can type more characters. Look at my comment below @Hitmands reply.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your post isn't clear at all, 
do you need to control the number of insertions in chars on the contenteditable element or do you just need to style the visible portion of the dom??

If you need to simulate the maxlength attribute that an input element normally has, you need to replicate this behaviour with javascript, CSS can't help you...

otherwise, if it's is just a presentation issue, you can do it with css using **em** unit...

```
<div contenteditable style="width: 20em"; height: 1em; line-height:1em; overflow:hidden;></div>
```

Comment: It does not work for me. At present, the best solution I found is to add this property to <h2> : `onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length <= 20)"` , but it block typing more signs than 20, not blocking typing when I reach the max-width and also I am able to hit enter button and type 1 char below the other, what change my contenteditable box height (which also should be blocked)